# Is there a way to demonstrate uniqueness of false-elim

Tags: types, agda

I can't remember if I've read this somewhere, but it is tempting to assume that ⊥ is an initial object. But then it must be possible to construct proofs based on the uniqueness of the ⊥-elim arrows.

Like this:

```
false-elim : forall {A : Set} -> False -> A
false-elim ()

false-iso : forall {A B : Set} -> (g : A -> False)
                               -> (f : A -> B) -> f == (f o false-elim o g)
```

That is, if there is an arrow from A into ⊥, then A is isomorphic to ⊥. Ok, if the assumption that (A -> ⊥) is an isomorphism is wrong, at least must be possible to show the uniqueness of ⊥-elim:

```
false-elim-uniq : forall {A B : Set} -> (f : A -> B)
                                     -> false-elim == (f o false-elim)
```

But this is not obvious, too. So, is ⊥-elim meant to be unique in (flavour of) intuitionistic type theory (Agda is based on)?

It is possible to construct the proof if an element of A can be constructed:

```
false-iso : forall {A B : Set} -> (g : A -> False)
                               -> (f : A -> B) -> A -> f == (f o false-elim o g)
```

But that's not quite the same statement. It does say I can prove homotopy of the said functions (and show A ≅ ⊥).

---

Given it some thought, I guess I can narrow down my problem to: if all I can show is a homotopy `f ~ (f o false-elim o g)`, what does the universal property of `false-elim` look like?

Comment: You probably need function extensionality.

Comment: @gallais hm, yes, but I wonder how it works without extensionality - does it mean `false-elim` is not unique? How is it a universal morphism then? Ok, getting homotopies involved, I can show homotopy `f ~ (f o false-elim o g)`, but then it is not quite clear what universality of `false-elim` looks like.

Comment: I don't think that unicity is provable without function extensionality. Which does not mean that `false-elim` is not unique.

Comment: @gallais thank you. Yes, function extensionality would still require a homotopy. I suppose I expected more built-in consequences for `false-elim` - not just special notation for "a function with no body", not just "this function is polymorphic in its return type". Oh well.